# Why does rand()%10+1 give me a number between 1-10?

Tags: c++, random, random-seed

Im fairly new to programming

So i was actually trying to figure something out

Why does rand()%10+1 give us a number between 1-10 whereas 32767%10 is actually 7?

Comment: Because you add 1 afterward. `rand() % 10` is between `0` and `9`, so `rand() % 10 + 1` is between `1` and `10`.

Comment: Obligatory link to [rand() Considered Harmful](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful)

Comment: Your title does not match your question.

Comment: You may be confusing `rand()` with `RAND_MAX`.

Comment: @user4581301 Probably too early for that.

Comment: I've edited the title to be consistent with the body of the question. I don't think that discrepancy was relevant to the information the OP is looking for. And I *think* I've managed to dig down to what the OP is actually confused about (though I may be wrong).

Answer (score 3):

I think I see the source of your confusion.

The fact that you referred to `rand()%10` in your title and `rand()%10+1` in the body of your question made that difficult.

You asked:

> Why does `rand()%10+1` give us a number between 1-10 whereas `32767%10` is actually 7?

It's because the function `N%10` is not monotonically increasing. As the value of `N` increases, the value of `N%10` goes up and down.

I think you're assuming:

- that `32767` is the maximum value returned by `rand()` (which it can be, but on my system it's `2147483647`, but that doesn't affect the point); and
- that if `32767` is the maximum value returned by `rand()`, then `32767%10`, which is 7, must be the maximum value of `rand()%10`.

Your second assumption is wrong. For any value `N` (we'll ignore negative values), `N%10` is the last digit of its decimal representation. If `rand()` returns 9, then `rand()%10` will be 9 and `rand()%10+1` will be 10 -- which is larger than the value of `32767%10+1`.

Answer (score -3):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{
    int randomnumber;
    randomnumber = rand() % 10;
    printf("%d\n", randomnumber);
    return 0;
}
```

When you run this code it will generate a number from 0 to 10 because of number **10** behind it (Because you want to **random to 10** so that is why is a 10) but it will generate from **0 to 9** only. That's why you need a **+1** at the end to generate random from **1 to 10**. That's all.

Comment: This does not answer the question and is poorly worded.

Comment: Should mention `srand()` too.